# Can a strong hadith be wrong? If so, what do I do?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

> The Prophet said, "If somebody takes some 'Ajwa dates every morning, he will not be effected by poison or magic on that day till night." (Another narrator said seven dates).  [Volume 7, Book 71, Number 663:](https://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/071-sbt.php#007.071.663)

This hadith is surely wrong if we use modern day knowledge, since it is a strong hadith (it being from Sahih Bukhari). How do we reconcile with wrong hadiths that are strong hadiths?

Comment: Why would it be wrong in "modern day knowledge"?  Has there been a study done that you know of that disproves it?  There's another hadith mention a certain type of poison and not all poisons.  So we have to look at all narrations and make a judgment.

Answer (score 3):

Scholars accept the possibility of a hadith being 'wrong' based on its *matn* (the content reported). [Al-Sakhawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Sakhawi) (d 1497) quotes [Abu'l-Faraj ibn al-Jawzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu%27l-Faraj_ibn_al-Jawzi) (d.1200) in *[Fath al-Mugeeth](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=81&idto=81&bk_no=82&ID=79)*:

> وكل حديث رأيته يخالف العقول، أو يناقض الأصول، فاعلم أنه موضوع، فلا
> تتكلف اعتباره، أي: لا تعتبر رواته، ولا تنظر في جرحهم. أو يكون مما
> يدفعه الحس والمشاهدة، أو مباينا لنص الكتاب، أو السنة المتواترة، أو
> الإجماع القطعي ; حيث لا يقبل شيء من ذلك التأويل.
>
> Every hadith you find against intellect or (find it) contradicting
> (well-established) principles, rest assured that it is fabricated.
> Therefore, you do not need to consider it i.e. do not take into account
> its narrators and do not look into their criticism. (Similarly,) if it is
> against senses and observations, or either in contrast with the
> Qur'an or *Al-Sunnah Al-Matwatira* (the well-established practices) or
> decisive consensus; such that it does not accept any other
> interpretation.

Therefore, *if* you are sure that hadith you have quoted has been falsified by modern day knowledge you may not accept it as a prophetic saying.

However, narrators may miss some important piece of information while reporting. This may lead to contradiction with what we know for sure. It is usually recommended to collect all reports on a subject to fill the gaps and see if the apparent contradiction is resolved.

Answer (score -2):

Science is based on Very Very limited knowledge of human beings. Its limits end, where the knowledge of Human beings end.

And compared to this science, knowledge of Allah is Unlimited. and Prophet Muhammad never said anything on its own, but he was divinely guided. So 100% sure, science is wrong in this case, as it can never ever reach that level, where it can fully give proof of everything in Islam to be 100% true, due to its limitations.

And Allah knows the best